# How to handle ajax Request in a complex-structured plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I've been looking how to handle ajax requests in a plugin with wordpress. I have a found a cool article about this in the codex. I think I got the basics but it seems I can't get my handler function to... well, handle the ajax request.

I have `my_plugin` structured like the wordpress plugin boilerplate I found on wppb.me.

So I have my javascript that does an ajax request like this in `my_plugin/public/js/my-script.js`

```
var postData = {
    'action': "my_action",
    /* some more data */
}
//ajaxurl var is correctly defined in the file
ajax(ajaxurl, function(response){ //this function is homemade and works correctly
    // do smth with response
}, postData)
```

This script is correctly enqueued in `my_plugin/public/class-my-plugin-public.php` like this :

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, 'all' );
```

I have a method inside `my-plugin/includes/class-my-plugin.php` that is supposed to add actions so that admin-ajax.php knows which function should handle the ajax call from client.

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', array($plugin_public, 'my_action') );
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', array($plugin_public, 'my_action') );
```

And finally, here is the handler method that is supposed to handle the ajax request in `my_plugin/public/class-my-plugin-public.php` :

```
function my_action() {
    //other stuff

    echo 'hello';

    wp_die(); //I've read this is compulsory in a tutorial for ajax requests
}
```

What I expected is :
My script is enqueued, and the ajax request is fired. Then, I add an action to tell wp-ajax which method is to handle this request, and I have prepared this function in my public facing class. So the response for the ajax request should be 'hello' string.

But the only response I get with this ajax request is a (400) bad response.

I couldn't find any tutorial out there featuring examples with a similar structure to the wordpress plugin boilerplate. Everything is in the same file in the examples.
My guess atm is that the action name I have to put in my postData var in  `my-script.js` might be wrong, because I'm adding the hook action like `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', array($plugin_public, 'my_action') );` and not just `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action') );`.
And the later example woudn't work since the `my_action` function and my `add_action()` are not called in the same file...

By the way, I have other hooks up and functional with this synthax so...

I would really appreciate any explanation or even hint.

Comment: `'action': my_action,` is probably the problem. `my_action` needs quotes around it or JavaScript is going to set `action` to be the value of a variable called `my_action`, which will be undefined. Also, is the `my_action` function actually  a method of a class?

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear, it was a bit hard to explain...
this `my_action` is the actual name of my handler function like `"my_action"`.

This function is a method of the `my-plugin-public` class. That is why I use the array synthax for the `add_action` directive (which is called in an other file).

There shouldn't be any problem with typo or namespace since this procedure works with other hooks that are not ajax-related